# Symfony, Doctrine order by foreign key even when the FK is null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets imagine I have an Entity like this

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ MyEntityRepository")
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Kind")
     */
    private $kind;
}
```

I want to query them and order them by kind.
Here what I do that in my repository

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

class MyEntityRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllOrdered()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->join('e.kind', 'k')
            ->orderBy('k.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(); 
    }
}
```

This work great but that completely ignore all line where the kind is null.

So how can I retrieve and order all entities even if the kind is null ?

Comment: Use `leftJoin` instead. of `join` `JOIN/INNER JOIN` will exclude records that do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an inner join. This is a more efficient query because it only retrieves records where there is a match between the 2 tables.

If you want to pick up null values, you need to use `leftJoin`. This should be used with care as these queries are heavier than `innerJoin` because all records in the base table are considered instead of just the matches.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

class MyEntityRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllOrdered()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->leftJoin('e.kind', 'k')
            ->orderBy('k.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(); 
    }
}
```